# deploy databricks workspace with powershell fails to deploy more than one worskapce

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, azure-databricks, infrastructure-as-code

Im trying to deploy the databrick workspace with yml pipeline that should run powershell script.

this is my function:

```
function Create-Databricks {
    param (
        [string] $rgName,
        [string] $dbName
    )
    
    az extension add --name databricks
    az databricks workspace create --resource-group $rgName --name $dbName --location 
    westeurope --output none

}
```

and this is my for each loop that has to create multiple resoures groups and their own databricks workspaces

```
foreach ($key in $iniContent["trainees"].Keys) {
# Get the trainee name
$traineeName = $iniContent["trainees"][$key]

# Set Azure context
# az account set --subscription "721fd46a-a810-4202-aa25-8b58b0410e1b"

$names = $traineeName -split ' '
$lastname = ($traineeName -split ' ')[1].Substring(0, [Math]::Min(5, 
$traineeName.IndexOf(" "))).ToLower()
# RG name
$resourceGroupName = "rg-academy-databricks-$lastname"
# SA name
$storageName = "stacademy$lastname"
# DB name
$databricksName = "dbs-academy-course-$lastname-001"
$accessconnectorName = "dbscon-academy-course-$lastname-001"
....

# Check if Databricks workspace exists
$dbExists = Get-AzDataBricksWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name 
$databricksName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $dbExists) {
    Write-Output "Databricks workspace $databricksName does not exist. Creating..."
    # Call function to create Databricks workspace if it doesn't exist
    Create-Databricks -rgName $resourceGroupName -dbName $databricksName -tags $tags
}
else {
    Write-Output "Databricks workspace $databricksName already exists. Skipping 
creation."
}
```

}

It is creating successfully the first interation and deployes resource group, storage account, and databricks workspace. But when it goes to the second iteration, it does eveything except databricks workspace and throws this error

> WARNING: Default enabled including preview versions for extension
> installation now. Disabled in May 2024. Use '--allow-preview true' to
> enable it specifically if needed. Use '--allow-preview false' to
> install stable version only.
>
> WARNING: Extension 'databricks' 0.10.2 is already installed.
>
> ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the
> traceback:
>
> ERROR: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('msrest.exceptions') at
> 2811310367824
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py",
> line 233, in invoke
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
> line 664, in execute
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
> line 731, in _run_jobs_serially
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
> line 712, in _run_job
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
> line 1035, in **call**
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/aaz/_poller.py",
> line 108, in result
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/core/tracing/decorator.py",
> line 76, in wrapper_use_tracer
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/aaz/_poller.py",
> line 130, in wait
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/aaz/_poller.py",
> line 83, in _start
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\AzureCliExtensionDirectory\databricks\azext_databricks\aaz\latest\databricks\workspace_create.py",
> line 206, in _execute_operations
>
> self.pre_operations()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\AzureCliExtensionDirectory\databricks\azext_databricks\custom.py",
> line 38, in pre_operations
>
> from msrestazure.tools import is_valid_resource_id, resource_id
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msrestazure/**init**.py",
> line 28, in
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msrestazure/azure_configuration.py",
> line 34, in
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msrest/**init**.py",
> line 28, in
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msrest/configuration.py",
> line 38, in
>
> File
> "D:\a_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msrest/universal_http/**init**.py",
> line 53, in
>
> File "", line 1173, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 171, in **enter**
>
> File "", line 116, in acquire
>
> _frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('msrest.exceptions') at 2811310367824
>
> To check existing issues, please visit:
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues

Comment: did you check existing issues in link in last line?  Do you have the latest version installed.  Looks like the release has lots of bugs.  This question should be asked the the github site.

Comment: i have latest azure-cli, the thing is that it used to work for two last week, it just started throwing this error this week so I dont know what is happening. Also, it runs green, it just does not deploy the databricks in the other iteration

Comment: It is probably the latest update.  Did you update any libraries?

Answer (score 0):

> Deploy data bricks workspace with PowerShell fails to deploy more than one workspace:

*Check below to avoid conflicts with your PowerShell script:*

- Move `az extension add` command from inside of the function to outside to install it only once. Otherwise, it will install and make a conflict every time the loop executes.
- And also check the extension release and update it if required using `az extension update --name databricks`.
- Use try catch blocks to catch exceptions under function block as it helps to understand the error or warning more clearly.
- Also check the pipeline configuration is upgraded and compatible with the CLI version you are using.

I tried your script in my environment by applying different use cases and was successful as shown.

```
az extension add --name databricks
function Create-Databricks {
    $rgName = "xxx"
    $dbName = "newdb2j" 
    az databricks workspace create --resource-group $rgName --name $dbName --location westeurope

}
```

[image]

[image]

```
$dbExists = Get-AzDataBricksWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $dbName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $dbExists) {
    Write-Output "Databricks workspace $databricksName does not exist. Creating..."
    Create-Databricks -rgName $rgName -dbName $dbName
}
else {
    Write-Output "Databricks workspace $databricksName already exists. Skipping 
creation."
}
```

[image]